# How do I extract velocity from this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation:$$0==-(at+c)dt^2+\frac{\left(t_0^2+t^2\right)}{4t_0^4}dx^2$$
In code, this is:

```
(4*dt^2*(c + a*t)^2*t0^4 - dx^2*(t^2 + t0^2)^2)/t0 == 0
```

How can I solve for $dt/dx$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Why can't you divide by `dx^2` and use `Sqrt`?

Comment: How are you going to use `DSolve`? You don't have a d.e. At least not in a mathematica language. I guess you want to form $\tfrac{dt}{dx}$ right? Try `Assuming[dt^2 != 0, 
   DivideSides[(4*dt^2*(c + a*t)^2*t0^4 - dx^2*(t^2 + t0^2)^2)/t0 == 
     0, dt^2]] // Expand // Collect[#, (dx^2) /dt^2] &`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way is to make the substitution dx -> vdt, then solve for v, like this

```
eqn = (4*dt^2*(c + a*t)^2*t0^4 - dx^2*(t^2 + t0^2)^2)/t0 == 0

Solve[eqn /. dx -> v dt, v] // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Or give the additional definition for v and use the ability of Solve to eliminate {dx,dt} at the same time you solve for v.

```
Solve[{v^2 == dx^2/dt^2, 
  4 dt^2 (c + a t)^2 t0^4 - dx^2 (t^2 + t0^2)^2 == 0}, v, {dx, dt}]

(*   {{v -> -((2 (c + a t) t0^2)/(t^2 + t0^2))}, 
      {v -> (2 (c t0^2 + a t t0^2))/(t^2 + t0^2)}}   *)
```

Get only one solution when restricting parameters

```
Solve[{v^2 == dx^2/dt^2, 
  4 dt^2 (c + a t)^2 t0^4 - dx^2 (t^2 + t0^2)^2 == 0, v > 0, a > 0, 
  c > 0, t >= t0 >= 0}, v, {dx, dt}, Reals]

(*   {{v -> ConditionalExpression[(2 c t0^2 + 2 a t t0^2)/(t^2 + t0^2), 
    t0 > 0 && t > t0 && c > 0 && a > 0]}}   *)
```